# MySQL how to extract data from one column using Substring and put to another column under same ID within same table

Tags: mysql, substring, extract

Let's say we have the table PEOPLE like

```
id      |   name        |       extracted
-----------------------------------------
1       |   Roger       |
-----------------------------------------
2       |   Anthony     |
-----------------------------------------
3       |   Maria       |
-----------------------------------------
```

---

We use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 3) FROM people.name WHERE name like '%thon%'
```

It will find "Anthony" and extract 3 first chars - so result is :
Ant

How to put this result against same id so the table looks like

```
id      |   name        |       extracted
-----------------------------------------
1       |   Roger       |
-----------------------------------------
2       |   Anthony     |       Ant
-----------------------------------------
3       |   Maria       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: do you want to update the table?

Comment: Yes, update the table - but how to do that with SUbString result - I can't combine...

Comment: `UPDATE people SET extracted = SUBSTRING(name, 1, 3) WHERE name like '%thon%'` -- try that.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? This is not only curiosity, but maybe you need some more specific solution to keep `name` and `extracted`in sync ?

Comment: UPDATE people SET extracted = SUBSTRING(name, 1, 3) WHERE name like '%thon%' - IT WORKS LIKE A BREEZE thanks to 491243 !
Dear Sylvain...I was not thinking yet about a sync of name and extracted...right now it's enough for me what I have from 491243...but your idea attracts to consider !

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
UPDATE people SET extracted = LEFT(`name`,3) WHERE `name` like '%thon%'
```